# Django ORM and pre_init signal

Tags: python, django

I have a class which has two children

```
class MyChild1(models.Model):
    attr1 = models.CharField(default='default value')

class MyChild2(models.Model):
    pass

class MyParent(models.Model):
    child1 = models.ForeignKey(Child1)
    child2 = models.ForeignKey(Child2)
```

In my package, I require the value of attr1 - and in order to make sure it exists, I initialize the parent with a signal:

```
def init_my_parent(sender, *args, **kwargs):
    child1 = MyChild1()
    child2 = MyChild2()

signals.pre_init.connect(init_my_parent,sender=MyParent)
```

This seems to work fine to ensure that child1 and child2 are always instantiated. However, even when I manually set child1 and child2 (`my_parent.child1 = child1` etc), `child1_id` and `child2_id` do not get set and the db throws an error

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: myparent.child1
```

I'm wondering what is causing this behavior? Somehow connecting that signal is causing a problem, but I'm not sure why. Here is a script similar to what I'm using:

```
c1 = MyChild1()
c2 = MyChild2()
c1.save()
c2.save()
p = MyParent()
p.child1 = c1
p.child2 = c2
p.save()
# Error thrown
```

Both of the values set in `init_my_parent` should be overwritten above, and thus everything should work the same as if the signal function wasn't there?

Comment: "Both of the values set in init_my_parent should be overwritten, and thus it shouldn't have an effect?" - Why/how are they being overwritten?

Comment: In your signal, you are instantiating two new child objects, but they are not being saved to the database, so they will not have `id` attributes.

Comment: I've added some detail to the end with the script I'd use to overwrite those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `pre_init` signal doesn't take instance parameter, so you are editing actual class (`sender`). Try using `post_init` signal which takes `instance` parameter, so you can change it:

```
def init_my_parent(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not hasattr(instance,'child1'): 
        instance.child1 = MyChild1()
        instance.child1.save()
    if not hasattr(instance,'child2'): 
        instance.child2 = MyChild2()
        instance.child2.save()

signals.post_init.connect(init_my_parent, sender=MyParent)
```

Comment: I presume you mean `sender.child1 = MyChild1()` etc.?
Since it is a pre init signal, they should be instantiated during that signal first, and then replaced with the new instances I created.
Even so, I did try this and same error occurs.

Comment: Aha, I see what is the problem. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks! I supposed I can check the *args to see if those variables are defined in the constructor - and use those if they are?

My query doesn't seem to return the correct values, but this could be unrelated.

Comment: No, you cannot do this, because changing arguments in the signal doesn't reflect in changes of actual arguments that are used in model. I don't see a problem with using `post_init` signal, as it is still executed before save is called. Maybe this is also the reason why your query doesn't work.

Comment: Right so this doesn't work because when loading from the database, after it loads the children, they get reset to empty instances. 

I fixed it with these lines: `if not hasattr(instance,'child1'): instance.child1 = Child1()` and `if not hasattr(instance,'child2'): instance.child2 = Child2()`

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyChild1(models.Model):
    attr1 = models.CharField(default='default value', max_length=100)

class MyChild2(models.Model):
    pass

class MyParent(models.Model):
    child1 = models.ForeignKey(MyChild1)
    child2 = models.ForeignKey(MyChild2
```

using class instead of def, then it is going to be fine.

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo, I am definitely using class. Will update